# How to format complex chained Linq statements for readibility?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, coding-style

I have some code like this:

```
var effects = xElement.Elements ( "Effects" ).Elements ( "Effect" ).Select (
    e => new Effect (
        ( EffectType ) Enum.Parse ( typeof ( EffectType ), ( string ) e.Elements ( "Type" ).FirstOrDefault ( ) ),
        e.Elements ( "Options" ).Any ( )
            ? e.Elements ( "Options" ).Select ( o => ( object ) o.Elements ( "Option" ).Select ( n => n.Value ).First ( ) )
            : null ) )
            .ToList ( );
```

But currently this doesn't look as readable and I am not sure where I should add a new line and/or indent for readability.

Any suggestions I could use to make consistent, readable linq blocks?

Comment: Here is my comment; don't use LINQ when it would be more clear as a simple loop through each element, grabbing properties, and then adding a new object to a list.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show it as an example. I am not sure how you could accomplish that with loops the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally subjective question, don't even know why I am answering it but here's what looks more readable **to me**:

```
var effects = xElement
    .Elements("Effects")
    .Elements("Effect")
    .Select(e => 
        new Effect(
            (EffectType)Enum.Parse(
                typeof(EffectType), 
                (string)e.Elements("Type").FirstOrDefault()
            ),
            e.Elements("Options").Any() 
                ? e.Elements("Options").Select(
                    o => o.Elements("Option").Select(n => n.Value).First()
                )
                : null
        ) 
    )
    .ToList();
```

or if you prefer the query syntax:

```
var effects = 
    from e in xElement.Elements("Effects").Elements("Effect")
    let effectType = 
        (EffectType)Enum.Parse(
            typeof(EffectType), 
            (string)e.Elements("Type").FirstOrDefault()
        )
    let options = 
        e.Elements("Options").Any() 
            ? e.Elements("Options").Select(
                  o => o.Elements("Option").Select(n => n.Value).First()
            )
            : null
    select new Effect(effectType, options);
```

Comment: This is what I would have written, almost exactly

Comment: This looks good indeed but now I am thinking why it uses a new line for .Elements("Effects"), .Elements("Effect"), but not Elements("Options"), Elements("Option")?

Comment: Thanks Darin, I was actually asking about e.Elements("Options").Any(), and o => o.Elements("Option") lines where I was assuming they will have new lines for e and .Elements("Options"), and/or .Any(), etc. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer small functions with clear names. Something like this:

```
    public void Parse()
    {
        //XElement xElement = blah...

        var elements = xElement.Elements("Effects").Elements("Effect");
        var converted = elements.Select(ConvertToEffect);
    }

    private static Effect ConvertToEffect(XElement e)
    {
        var value = ConvertEnum((string) e.Elements("Type").FirstOrDefault());
        var option = GetOption(e.Elements("Options"));

        return new Effect(value, option);
    }

    private static EffectType ConvertEnum(string value)
    {
        return (EffectType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EffectType), value);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> GetOption(IEnumerable<XElement> e)
    {
        var any = e.Elements("Options").Any();
        if (any)
        {
            return e.Elements("Options").Select(o => (object) o.Elements("Option").Select(n => n.Value).First());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use query expression instead. I think it'll be more readable.

Comment: Thanks, can you please show with an example as I wouldn't be able to write the most elegant query syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I would format it something like this:

```
var effects =
  xElement.Elements("Effects").Elements("Effect")
  .Select (
    e => new Effect(
      (EffectType)Enum.Parse(
        typeof(EffectType),
        (string)e.Elements("Type").FirstOrDefault()
      ),
      e.Elements("Options").Any() ?
        e.Elements("Options")
        .Select(o => (object)o.Elements("Option")
        .Select(n => n.Value).First())
        : null
    )
  )
  .ToList ();
```